# ASP.Net Repeater with multiple HiddenFields

Tags: asp.net, datarepeater, hiddenfield

I am currently trying to use a repeater. There is a field that has a link button, a radio list and several hidden fields.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="radList" runat="server"></asp:RadioButtonList>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add"></asp:LinkButton>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnLogNum" runat="server" Value='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LogNumber") %>' />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnStationID" runat="server" Value='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "StationID") %>' />
```

If I edit the code so that there is only one hidden field, the link button executes normally. If I keep the second hidden field, I get the error...

Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException..... the status code returned from the server was: 500

Any suggestions are appreciated.